# compute sample probabilities given a poisson distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sampling, poisson-distribution

I have read through a large number of stack posts about hypothesis testing on Poisson distributions. Some examples:

- [Calculating test statistic of a poisson distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316486/calculating-test-statistic-of-a-poisson-distribution)
- [Hypothesis testing with Poisson Data](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2532273/hypothesis-testing-with-poisson-data)
- [hypothesis testing using poisson distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73907/hypothesis-testing-using-poisson-distribution)

The above four posts ask this question in slightly different ways, yet the answers obtained are not recognizably similar. Thus I will ask the question here in hopes of obtaining an authoritative answer.

#### The question

I have a Poisson distribution with known mean $\mu$. What is the probability of obtaining a single sample from that distribution which is greater than some value $x$?

Relatedly, what is the probability of drawing $n$ samples from that distribution which have an average value greater than $\bar{x} = \sum_i^n{x_i} / n$.?

Since the variance of the Poisson distribution is equal to its mean $\mu$, we may compute a Z-score like:

$$
z = \frac{x-\mu}{\sqrt{\mu}}
$$

I have not seen this expressed explicitly anywhere, but I assume the generalization to multiple samples is accomplish like:

$$
z = \frac{\bar{x}-\mu}{\sqrt{\mu / n}}
$$

With a Z-score in hand, one can look up the probability using the Z distribution CDF. In python:

```py
import scipy.stats
p = scipy.stats.norm.cdf(z)
```

Firstly, I am wondering if the above characterization of the approach is correct. This is simply the understanding I have gleaned from searching the topic.

Secondly, where does this approach come from? For example, in the case of an academic paper, whom would I cite about such an approach?

Finally, the [normal approximation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83283/normal-approximation-to-the-poisson-distribution) is sometimes but not always mentioned in posts on this topic. Does the above approach use the normal approximation? As such, is it inappropriate for $\mu$ with smaller values? If so, what would be an appropriate test?

Comment: Yes, excuse my poor notation!

I meant to refer to $\bar{x}$ as the average value of $n$ samples drawn from a poisson distribution with mean $\mu$. The question concerns the probability of obtaining that value ($\bar{x}$) or greater.

This is slightly different from the original question, as it involves multiple samples instead of a single sample. How could the equation you posted be modified to handle multiple samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If random variable $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda),$ then $E(X) = Var(X) = \lambda.$ The PDF is $p_k = P(X = k) = e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k/k!,$
for integer $k \ge 0.$ The CDF is $F_X(k) = P(X \le k) = \sum_{k=0}^x p_k$ and
$P(X>k) = 1 - F_X(k).$

> Example: If $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 3),$ then $P(X = 4) = 01680,$ $P(X\le 4)=0.8153,$ $P(X > 4) = 0.1847$ according to the following computations in R:

```
lam = 3;  dpois(4, lam);  ppois(4, lam);  1 - ppois(4, lam)
[1] 0.1680314
[1] 0.8152632
[1] 0.1847368
```

If $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ are a random sample from $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda)$ and $\bar X = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1} ^n X_i$ then 
$$n\bar X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim \mathsf{Pois}(n\lambda).$$

For $\lambda$ sufficiently large, both of your normal approximations
may be useful.

> Example: If $\lambda = 36$ then $P(X \le 30)=0.1806$ can be approximated
>   by $P(X^\prime \le 30.5) = 0.1797,$ where $X^\prime \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\,u = 36,\, \sigma=6).$ Standardizing, the approximation is
>   $$P(X \le 30) = P(X < 30.5) = P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} < \frac{30.5-36}{6}\right)\\ \approx P(Z < -0.9167) = 0.1797,$$
>   where the value obtained from printed tables of the standard normal CDF, rounding to $-0.92,$ is a little different.

```
lam = 36;  ppois(30, 36) 
[1] 0.1806255
pnorm(30.5, 36, 6)
[1] 0.1796587
pnorm((30.5 - 36)/6)
[1] 0.1796587
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

So to be clear: the Z score approach I have seen around does use the normal approximation (duh, the Z distribution _is_ a normal distribution). However, for the purposes of computing the CDF of `n` samples, $n\bar X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim \mathsf{Pois}(n\lambda)$ would do the trick. In python:

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
n = 10  # number of samples
xbar = 10  # avg of sampled data
mu = 8  # assumed rate
p = poisson.cdf(n*xbar, n*mu)
# 0.9868311451240662
```

Comment: Clearing up the above comment's python example: `python -c 'from scipy.stats import poisson; n = 10 ; xbar = 10; mu = 8; p = poisson.cdf(n*xbar, n*mu)'`